# VBA accessing Web Service and parsing result

Tags: vba, soap

I need to parse a specific Node (Token) so that I can use it in my next API request.  I get the SOAP XML response fine (displayed below).  I get stuck at the last line of this Subroutine, compile error: argument not optional.  Once I set variable LastToken - I would like to see it in a MsgBox to verify it.  Can't seem to find the right syntax to get through this.

VBA Code (Using Access 2016)

```
Sub InvokeAuthenticate()

    'Declare our working variables
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim LastToken As String
    'Set and Instantiate our working objects
    Set objHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    sURL = "http://netforum.avectra.com/xweb/netforumxmlondemand.asmx"
    'SOAP envelope for submission to the Web Service
    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:ns=""http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Header/>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "     <ns:Authenticate>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "          <ns:userName>notdisplayed</ns:userName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "          <ns:password>notdisplayed</ns:password>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "     </ns:Authenticate>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"
    'invoke the web service
    objHTTP.Open "Post", sURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    objHTTP.send (sEnv)
    MsgBox objHTTP.responseText
    'below is where the trouble starts, I need syntax help

    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.Load (objHTTP.responseText)
    LastToken = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(Token)


End Sub
```

SOAP XML response coming through successfully as objHTTP.responseText:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <AuthorizationToken soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
         <Token>7e6345ef-10c5-4b0b-9731-26db2ebdcd1d</Token>
      </AuthorizationToken>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
         <AuthenticateResult>http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/</AuthenticateResult>
      </AuthenticateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are passing Token as though it's an undeclared variable, not as the literal string "Token"

Comment: I tried that again as literal string "Token" and I get the same message: compile error: argument not optional

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of nodes, not a string.  It should be something like `LastToken = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Token")(0).nodeValue`

Comment: Thank you Tim, tried that and got Runtime Error 91: Object Variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you used, and indicate where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (loading the XML from a worksheet cell for testing purposes):

```
Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim el As Object, txt
Dim XML As String

XML = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value

oDoc.validateOnParse = True
oDoc.LoadXML XML

txt = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("Token")(0).Text

Debug.Print txt '>> 7e6345ef-10c5-4b0b-9731-26db2ebdcd1d
```